# Lifting function fields to characteristic zero

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a finite field and $K$ a function field over $k$. Then the smooth projective curve associated to $K$ can be lifted to $W(k)$, as the obstruction to lifting is $H^2(X,T_X)$ and therefore for dimension reasons, we are in the clear. My question is what can we say about the function field: can it also be lifted to $W(k)$? The problem here is that unless $K$ is separable, $\text{Spec }K$ will not be smooth over $k$.

Comment: What precisely, do you mean by lifting the function field to $W(k)$? The function field of the lifted curve will live over $Frac(W(k))$.

Comment: @EvansGambit yes, the function field of the lifted curve will be over $Frac(W(k))$, but I'm talking about $K$ itself.

Comment: @curiousmathguy Just to repeat what Evans Gambit asked: What would it mean for Spec $K$ to lift to characteristic zero? There is a scheme $X\to Spec W(k))$ whose special fibre is Spec $K$? Such a scheme will not even be of finite type over $W(k)$ because Spec $K$ is not of finite type over Spec $k$.

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar Apologies for being unclear. Yes such a scheme would not be of finite type, but I'd still be curious about it. I'd also be curious about the existence of a formal scheme over $W(k)$ whose speical fibre is $\text{Spec } K$.

Comment: Probably it doesn't exist. Suppose $X$ is affine and normal. (If an $X$ exists with the property you desire, one can also cook up a normal affine example by taking a suitable dense open probably.) Then $X=Spec $ $R$ with the property that $R/p = K$. So $p$ is maximal. Thus, $R$ is zero-dimensional.  Hence a field...

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar sorry, I'm confused. The ideal $(p)$ is also a maximal ideal in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ and \mathbb{Z}_p$ is not a field...

Comment: Whoops I made a silly error. Apologies.